# Create a sub-image from context

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I was wondering if there was a way to create a `CGImage` corresponding to a rectangle inside the context?

What I am doing right now:

I am using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` to create a `CGImage` from a context. Then, I use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to extract that sub-image.

Anil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
static CGImageRef createImageWithSectionOfBitmapContext(CGContextRef bigContext,
    size_t x, size_t y, size_t width, size_t height)
{
    uint8_t *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(bigContext);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(bigContext);
    size_t bytesPerPixel = CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerPixel(bigContext) / 8;
    data += x * bytesPerPixel + y * bytesPerRow;
    CGContextRef smallContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(data,
        width, height,
        CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerComponent(bigContext), bytesPerRow,
        CGBitmapContextGetColorSpace(bigContext),
        CGBitmapContextGetBitmapInfo(bigContext));
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(smallContext);
    CGContextRelease(smallContext);
    return image;
}
```

or this:

```
static CGImageRef createImageWithSectionOfBitmapContext(CGContextRef bigContext,
    size_t x, size_t y, size_t width, size_t height)
{
    uint8_t *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(bigContext);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(bigContext);
    size_t bytesPerPixel = CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerPixel(bigContext) / 8;
    data += x * bytesPerPixel + y * bytesPerRow;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data,
        height * bytesPerRow, NULL);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(width, height,
        CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerComponent(bigContext),
        CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerPixel(bigContext),
        CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(bigContext),
        CGBitmapContextGetColorSpace(bigContext),
        CGBitmapContextGetBitmapInfo(bigContext),
        provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty elegant solution and it works for my case! Thanks.

Comment: There was a bug in the first function.  I have fixed it.  Presumably you were using the second function.

Comment: I was using the first function. Yeah, I saw the bug but, the main idea was what I borrowed. Thanks! I have to point out one thing though. I could not see much difference between my previous implementation (as mentioned in the question) and this in terms of user experience. Probably, the bottleneck is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cropped image as follows as mentioned [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-crop-an-image.html),

For eg:-

```
UIImage *image = //original image
CGRect rect = //cropped rect
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

You need to get the CGImage from context to use the above code to crop it. You can use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` as mentioned in question. Here is [the documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I have the image data in a `CGContext`. I want to create an image from a rectangular region inside that context and not from inside a `UIImage`.

Comment: In that case you are right, you need to create a CGImage first and then use the above code to crop it.

Comment: That seems like a lot of overhead. Isn't it? If you want to dynamically change context (based on touch or something similar in realtime), the experience tends to degrade.

Comment: As of now you have to do that way. Check documentation for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create your CGBitmapContext with a buffer that you allocated, and create a CGImage from scratch using the same buffer. With the context and the image sharing a buffer, you can draw into the context and then create a CGImage with that section of the master image.

Note that if you draw into the same context afterward, the cropped image may actually pick up the changes (depending on just how much shared-referencing-instead-of-copying is going on internally). Depending on what you're doing, you may or may not find this desirable.

Comment: A `CGImage` is immutable.  When you create one, it makes a private copy of the bitmap data.